# Reading CVPoint from File

Tags: c, opencv

I am interested in reading points of type CvPoint* from a file, but I have tried the standard notation (x,y). It gives incorrect values when I try to verify the output. what is the format for reading CvPoint in a file.

point.txt

```
(1,1)
```

main.cpp

```
points  = (CvPoint*)malloc(length*sizeof(CvPoint*));
points1 = (CvPoint*)malloc(length*sizeof(CvPoint*));
points2 = (CvPoint*)malloc(length*sizeof(CvPoint*));
fp = fopen(points.txt, "r");
fscanf(fp, "%d", &(length));
printf("%d  \n", length);
i = 1;
while(i <= length)
{
  fscanf(fp, "%d", &(points[i].x));
  fscanf(fp, "%d", &(points[i].y));
  printf("%d  %d \n",points[i].x, points[i].y);
  i++;
}
```

It prints:

```
1


12  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach using the same format for your text file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ifstream file("points.txt");
    string line;
    size_t start, end;
    Point2f point;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
         start = line.find_first_of("(");
     end = line.find_first_of(",");
     point.x = atoi(line.substr(start + 1, end).c_str());
     start = end;
     end = line.find_first_of(")");
     point.y = atoi(line.substr(start + 1, end - 1).c_str());
     cout << "x, y: " << point.x << ", " << point.y << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```